# How to avoid re-render in react-redux connected component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have react-redux component SideBar.js which is subscribing to slice of redux state. When the redux state changes, this component gets re-rendered unnecessarily even it does not subscribe to that changing state in redux. Since my state is nested, i do not want to do deep comparisons in shouldComponentUpdate() to avoid re-rendering ... how can i avoid extra re-rendering ?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        guestLogin:{
            status : state.guestLogin.status,
            marketPlace:state.guestLogin.marketPlace,
            newsFeed:state.guestLogin.newsFeed
        },
        accountLogin:{
            showMemberPosts:state.accountLogin.showMemberPosts,
            newsFeed: state.accountLogin.newsFeed,
            marketPlace:state.accountLogin.marketPlace,
            userInfo:state.accountLogin.userInfo
        },
        marketPlace:{
            reset:state.marketPlace.reset,
            disableFilters:state.marketPlace.disableFilters,
            filters:state.marketPlace.filters,


        }

    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        guestMarketPlaceClickHandler :()=>{dispatch(marketPlaceCLickHandlerDispatcher())},
        guestNewsFeedClickHandler:()=>{dispatch(newsFeedClickHandlerDispatcher())},
        memberMarketPlaceClickHandler:()=>{dispatch(marketPlaceCLickHandlerDispatcher())},
        memberNewsFeedClickHandler:()=>{dispatch(newsFeedClickHandlerDispatcher())},
        myPostsClickHandler:()=>{dispatch(myPostsClickHandlerDispatcher());},
        dispatch:(action)=>{dispatch(action)}
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)((SideBar));
```

Comment: There is no other way unfortunately. Try to minimize the number of deep comparisons needed to check if the component needs to be rerendered. Even deep comparisons are far less costly versus needlessly rerendering a large component.

Comment: @ShawnAndrews.... as you can see my slice of state has 10 key value pairs, is it ok to do 10 comparsions in shouldComponentUpdate() ?

Comment: can you clarify, what part of state does change for which you dont want your component to re-render? can you gice example for such a slice?

Comment: @deezg.. for e.g.. initial full state for marketPlace has key value pair - isLoading : false which become isLoading: true during some dispatch... at this dispatch,, my SideBar.js component also gets re-rendered even it is not subscribed to this key value pair in slice of marketPlace state

Comment: ten comparisons is reasonable. it is also much better than the alternative of rerendering

Comment: @ManpreetSingh ok, i see now, thanks for claryfing that. just wanted to check that its not something outside of the reducer responsible for that particular slice. well, as shawn said, you can either do manual comparisons or make your reducers more granular to reflect needs of your components.

Comment: @deezg... thanks so mch for help

Comment: @ShawnAndrews.. thanks for helping out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting your component to redux makes it a PureComponent. That is, it will do a shallow comparison of the props to decide if it needs to re-render. By nesting your store values in `mapStateToProps` you are guaranteeing that the shallow comparison will fail.

That is, `guestLogin: {...}` creates a new object for the value of guestLogin every time.

You can either use `reselect` or an equivalent solution to create selectors which return the same objects while the state doesn't change, or just make your mapStateToProps shallow, eg..

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        glStatus : state.guestLogin.status,
        glMarketPlace:state.guestLogin.marketPlace,
        glNewsFeed:state.guestLogin.newsFeed
        alShowMemberPosts:state.accountLogin.showMemberPosts,
        alNewsFeed: state.accountLogin.newsFeed,
        alMarketPlace:state.accountLogin.marketPlace,
        alUserInfo:state.accountLogin.userInfo
        mpReset:state.marketPlace.reset,
        mpDisableFilters:state.marketPlace.disableFilters,
        mpFilters:state.marketPlace.filters,
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks for helping... do u think if i can break my reducers to more granular state.. that would help ?

Comment: reducers don't really come into it. After any action is dispatched to the store all mapStateToProps functions will run and merge their results into the component's props. The component will do the shallow comparison with the previous props and render accordingly. Preventing the render is all about making sure that those top-level props objects don't change unnecessarily.